# How to add values to available part in multiselect picklist using apex?

Tags: apex, multi-select

I want to add some values to the **available** part of the multi-select picklist.

The below code adds the values to **selected** part of the multi-select picklist

```java
//SetupObj__c is custom object
//ObjectsSelected__c is multi-select picklist
SetupObj__c a = [SELECT ObjectsSelected__c FROM SetupObj__c WHERE ObjectsSelected__c!= null limit 1];
a.ObjectsSelected__c='Bank__c;Shop__c';
update a;//This adds value in selected part and not in available part
```

Is there a way to add values to the **available** part of the multi-select picklist using apex?

Comment: "Selected" values are what is stored in the database for the record you are returning in your SOQL. You are simply updating the database record to push two values into that field. Available options are rendered as part of the metadata for your field configuration to the end user.

Comment: @TSmith Thanks for the reply! Can we add values to metadata for the field configuration (Available options) using apex?

Comment: If you are looking to present those available options to the end user by a page like Visualforce, you could use something like [selectOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm) extended by Apex properties.

Comment: @TSmith I am doing the development in LWC. Hence I cannot use selectOptions. If adding values to Available values is not possible through apex, I am planning to use dual list box.